# AMI BIOS POST Beep коды

Tags: bios

На какой частоте пищит `AMI BIOS` при успешном прохождении `POST`?

Comment: Есть три предложения: 1. дизассемблировать BIOS и посмотреть все места где идет чтение/запись порта 42h (рядом должна быть установка двух младших бит порта 61h).  2. Найти знакомого с хорошим слухом, который скажет какая нота. 3. Использовать тюнер (прибор или программу)

Comment: 1.Я не знаю ассемблер 2.Не думаю,что биос пищит в ноту,но можно попробовать 3.Самое простое,но не имею компа с AMIBIOS.Ну как,он есть,но немного сломался,из-за чего этот пункт становится самым дорогим и(или) долгим ибо на матери отгорела нога на сокете

Comment: Дополните вопрос вам зачем частоту писка биоса определить требуется.?

Comment: Так,проект один пишу на родненьком сишарпе

Answer (score 2):

Частота звука тут ни при чем. Смотрите по длине и количеству звуковых сигналов:

> **1 короткий** звуковой сигнал - **Успешный POST**

[Список бип-кодов](http://pk-help.com/workstation/pisk-pisk-comp/)

Comment: Мне нужна именно частота,это я и так знаю.